# Google Apps Script - Making a url request using sha1 and base64 encode

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to make a url request with Google Apps Script and for that, I need to enncode my login and password using a sha 1 algorithm and a base64 encoding. In the documantation for the request, I have the following php code :

`$string = "loginpassword2017-15-04T09:25:00";
   $hash = sha1($string, true);
   $hash = base64_encode($hash);`

So in Google Apps Script, i use the following code :

`function GetSHA1(input) {
     var rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, input);
     var txtHash = '';
     for (j = 0; j <rawHash.length; j++) {
       var hashVal = rawHash[j];
       if (hashVal < 0)
         hashVal += 256; 
       if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1)
        txtHash += "0";
       txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
       }
     return txtHash;
   }`

and then the function

`Utilities.base64Encode`

Finally I make the url request but authentication is unsuccessful. Does someone know how to do a php sha1 and base64encode in Google Apps Script ? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'authentication is unsuccessful'?

Comment: It is a url request to connect to a webservice
I actually found the problem, the different sha1 I tested on google apps script differ from the one of php (I tested the encryption in php and tested that in google apps script and it worked)

Comment: Now my problem is to find a google apps script that is identical to the one of php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the **`Byte[]`** array returned from the **`Utilities::computeDigest`** directly to a **`Utilities::base64EncodeWebSafe`** invocation. So you could do something like the following:

```
function getLoginHash(loginData) {

    return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, loginData));

}
```